# Why can't I change directory

Tags: unix

I'm trying to move directory to another directory.
But I can't only change include directory which includes header files for database in C programming.

First, I typed "mv include /usr/include" in terminal so that change directory.
Then Error message shows up which says "rename mysql.h to usr/include Operation not permitted".

I want it for #include .

Could you please help me to find solution?

Best regards,

Comment: You are most likely doing it wrong, can you please explain what you **REALLY** want? [take a look at this](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: This is not related to C or mysql

Comment: You need to be on StackExchange with this question. mv is a unix command to move files but is also used to rename them. cd is the command to switch into another directory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but command line interaction.

Comment: @McNets It is related to C, he's trying to #include some headers.

Comment: What I really want is to include mysql.h in C programming.
But all header file locates different directory, So I tried to move them but can't.

Comment: The top voted answer should be accepted @Shuta.  Most like your program doesn't have permissions to write into the include directory.

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to move your include files to the system include directory - it's read only.

Instead, use the command line `-I` argument to force the compiler to check your directories as well as the system ones e.g.

```
cc -I/path/to/my/sql/includes mycprogram.c
```

You'll probably find you also need to use the `-L` and `-l` switches at some point soon.